# Creating a method that will procedurally write out console text like a mini game & dynamically changing still-text

Tags: c#, .net, console

I am creating a presentation for my Internship project and I figured what would be a cooler and more appropriate way than to do it in a Console Application.

I need help with 2 code snippets

1. This snippet procedurally writes out text and it works well but runs sub-optimally (hogs resources)

   ```
   static void SleeperText(string text, int interval)
   {
       char[] SlowPrint = text.ToCharArray();
       foreach (char letter in SlowPrint)
       {
           Write(letter);
           Thread.Sleep(interval);
       }
   ```
2. This snippet is meant to be a graphic representation of what a salt would look like (for demonstration purposes) but flickers the whole Console.

   ```
   static char RandomAsciLetter()
   {
       char charsi = (ascii[r.Next(tempstring.Length)]);
       return charsi;
   }
   static string RandomAsciCombo()
   {
       string stringsi = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}", RandomAsciLetter(),
           RandomAsciLetter(), RandomAsciLetter(), RandomAsciLetter(),
           RandomAsciLetter(), RandomAsciLetter(), RandomAsciLetter(), 
           RandomAsciLetter(), RandomAsciLetter(), RandomAsciLetter());
       return stringsi;     
   }
   void Main()
   {
       do
       {
           while (!KeyAvailable)
           {
               Thread.Sleep(10);
               Clear();
               Write("[ Esc ] to exit.");
               Write("\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n");
               WriteLine(String.Format("Salt:\t{0}{1}", RandomAsciCombo(), RandomAsciCombo()));

           }
       } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
       ReadLine();
   }
   ```

What is a better way to run the first snippet, and how do I remove the flickering for the second?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to remove the flickering (the only improvement I could think of is to optimize the printing like that, that you only update characters, which aren't already printed. This however probably isn't very significant), as the console is meant for text only representation and not graphical .

Comment: I was imagining something like that, or to overwrite the 'salt' display with an empty string and then constantly overwrite it in a loop. That would limit the flickering to only happen in the salt, which would still result in a more clean presentation overall..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove flickering, do not clear the screen but rather set cursor position and write there.

To remove the annoying cursor position change, just hide it.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            while (true)
            {
                if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                    break;

                Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 10);
                Console.Write(GetString());
            }
        }

        private static char GetChar()
        {
            return (char) Random.Next(65, 92);
        }

        private static string GetString()
        {
            return $"{GetChar()}{GetChar()}{GetChar()}{GetChar()}{GetChar()}";
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a skeleton, you will likely need some extra helpers ...

Comment: I mean, since I don't clear the screen, one needs to think differently about how to draw things.